# Error with import operation in database 11g release 1 and developer 10g

Tags: oracle

I installed Oracle Database 11G in the folder (E:\DB11)and successfully imported a user to it.

But when you install the developer 10G IN FOLDER (E:\DEV10) and try to do a user import into the  database ORACLE 11G, i am  receiving the following error message below . In addition, there is no possibility to run this command:

sqlplus  /as sysdba

i.e. after setup developer 10g the command from sqlplus for developer `/as sysdba` doesn't work. Since I can logon as another user such as system.

[image: error message 1]
[image: error message 2]

Comment: `SQLPlusW.exe` has been deprecated ages ago and won't work with Oracle 11. You need to use the `sqlplus.exe` (without the `W`) comand line tool that came with Oracle 11. It also seems you are using the wrong `impdp.exe`.  Additionally what exactly do you mean with "developer 10g"? Are you referring to "SQL Developer" from Oracle? Or to "PL/SQL Developer" from Allround Automations"? Those are two **very** different products.

Comment: (@a_horse) ... or is it Oracle Developer Suite (a.k.a *Forms & Reports Builders*)?

Comment: i mean use oracle 10g form builder , and i am using toad tool to doing import and command prompt (c:>imp username/password file=path full=y ) but i getting error